# C#/.NET: Testing BackgroundWorker with NUnit

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, unit-testing, backgroundworker

This test fails when it is run with the NUnit console runner. It works if I run just that test with TestDriven.NET, but not if I run the entire suite with TestDriven.NET:

```
[Test]
public void BackgroundWorkerFiresRunWorkerCompleted()
{
  var runner = new BackgroundWorker();
  ManualResetEvent done = new ManualResetEvent(false);
  runner.RunWorkerCompleted += delegate { done.Set(); };

  runner.RunWorkerAsync();

  bool res = done.WaitOne(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));
  // This assert fails:
  Assert.IsTrue(res, "RunWorkerCompleted was not executed within 10 seconds");
}
```

I suspect the problem have something to do with not having a message-loop, but I am not sure.

What are the requirements for using BackgroundWorker?

Is there a workaround to make the test work?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I don't think that it has to do with the message pump, since tests usually run in a blocking fashion anyways. But it may be that the event is invoked on the "UI" thread, which uses a windows message which does not get handled.

So, if the problem was the message pump or windows messages not being handled, you could try like this to replace your current `bool res = done.WaitOne(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));` line:

```
DateTime end = DateTime.Now.AddSeconds(10);
bool res = false;
while ((!res) && (DateTime.Now<end)) {
   Application.DoEvents();
   res = done.WaitOne(0):
}
```

Comment: We've found DoEvents() is only required when the test (or a previous test in the same test run) instantiates a Windows form or control. Why?

Comment: Because for any WinForms control, window messages need to be passed through the message pump, which doesn't happen if you don't call `DoEvents()`.

Answer (score 0):

Are you missing a BGW DoWork event handler?

Comment: The actual class I want to test subclasses BackgroundWorker and overrides OnDoWork(). But it makes no difference if I add a DoWork event-handler. The RunWorkerCompleted event-handler is still not run.

Answer (score -2):

Just add a Sleep before your:

`Assert.IsTrue(res, "RunWorkerCompleted was not executed within 10 seconds");`

Something like this:

`System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(10000);`

Comment: But that would make the test always take at least 10 seconds, when it should normally finish in milliseconds.